# Is this sentence correct? It seems wrong, but I can’t pinpoint why!

Tags: grammatical-number, irregular-plurals

I am proofing work for someone and this sentence seems incorrect, but I'm not sure why I think that. Is it truly incorrect? I feel like 'comes' should be 'come'.

> He stumbles back downstairs to the kitchen, feeling the weight of the last few days comes crashing down on top of him.

Answer (score 1):

> He stumbles back downstairs to the kitchen, feeling the weight of the
>   last few days comes crashing down on top of him.

You can use "come" instead of "comes". The that-clause is then turned into a catenative construction - the verb "come" is the head of the non-finite clause. Perception verbs, which obviously include the verb "feel",are peculiar in taking a plain verb form : see,hear,feel.. someone/something come.